# Can't connect to static VPN from docker compose

Tags: vpn, docker, openvpn, docker-compose

I'm trying to create a symetric VPN server with openvpn in a docker-compose. Here it is:

```
---
version: "3"
services:
  vpn: 
    image: whitebox/vpn:0.2
    networks: 
      - standard
    tty: true
    ports: 
      - "1194:1194/udp"
    volumes:
      - ./server:/home/server:ro
      - ./static.key:/home/static.key:ro
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_MODULE
    restart: always
    networks:
      standard:
        ipv4_address: "10.10.0.254"
  web:
    image: tutum/apache-php
    volumes:
      - ./web:/var/www/html:ro
      - ./client:/home/client:ro
    networks: 
      standard:
        ipv4_address: "10.10.0.2"
networks:
  standard:
    driver: bridge
    ipam: 
      config:
        - subnet: 10.10.0.0/16
```

When it is launched, I (temporarly) manually install openvpn, do some basics configs and launch the service. Everything seems to work just fine, except I can't connect to it from any device.

Server configuration file:

```
ifconfig 10.10.0.254 10.10.0.10
verb 3
secret static.key
keepalive 1 10
persist-key
persist-tun
proto udp
port 1195
dev tun
status /home/vpn.log
```

Client configuration file:

```
remote 192.168.37.137 1194
dev tun 
ifconfig 10.10.0.10 10.10.0.254
secret static.key
```

The strange thing about this is that I tried mounting the exact same server on a simple VM and everything works. The client can connect to it and access the 10.10.0.0/16 network. Although, here is the connexion log for the client:

```
Wed Aug 11 00:37:16 2021 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Wed Aug 11 00:37:16 2021 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Wed Aug 11 00:37:16 2021 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.10.0.10 peer 10.10.0.254
Wed Aug 11 00:37:16 2021 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]192.168.37.137:1194
Wed Aug 11 00:37:16 2021 UDP link local (bound): [AF_INET][undef]:1194
Wed Aug 11 00:37:16 2021 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]192.168.37.137:1194
```

And the corresponding container-based server:

```
Wed Aug 11 07:34:40 2021 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Wed Aug 11 07:34:40 2021 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Wed Aug 11 07:34:40 2021 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Wed Aug 11 07:34:40 2021 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.10.0.254 peer 10.10.0.10
Wed Aug 11 07:34:40 2021 Could not determine IPv4/IPv6 protocol. Using AF_INET
Wed Aug 11 07:34:40 2021 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
Wed Aug 11 07:34:40 2021 UDPv4 link local (bound): [AF_INET][undef]:1195
Wed Aug 11 07:34:40 2021 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_UNSPEC]
```

As you can see, no connexion is made.
Anyone has any idea why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the ports are properly configured.

You are forwarding port 1194 to your container but OpenVPN is configured to listen to port 1195.

Comment: Can't believe i lost so much time on this... Thanks mate